# Can't use new M2 SSD - Motherboard & Device Manager recognizes it, Windows Doesn't?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

[image: disk management screenshot]

The circled images are the SN850 discussed in this thread.

I just bought a new 2tb WD Black SN850 SSD and I'm having trouble getting it working.  I added it to the M2 slot on my already built/running system and I want to convert everything over to using the new drive.  I currently have a 500gb Samsung 860 Evo SSD w/ Win10 as my primary and an old school 1tb hhd used just for storage of media.  I'm wanting to copy everything over and just use my new SN850 with the others as backups.

My problem:

My MSI X570 Gaming Plus mobo recognized it in BIOS, Device Manager recognized it, the WD Dashboard recognized it (Firmware is up to date) and Macrium recognized it.  All auto Windows updates had been downloaded and updated.  However, Disk Manager, Windows Recovery and File Explorer would not recognize it at first.  Once I used Macrium Free to clone my primary drive to my new SN850, those programs recognize it now but only as a 500gb capacity clone.  It's as if it cloned over the exact storage/capacity of my primary and isn't even acknowledging there is another 1.5tb of unused space.

How do I utilize the rest of this space?  Looking at it in Macrium, it looks like it recognizes it as a drive w/ 376gb of used space out of a maximum 465gb, with another 1.36tb that is greyed out and appears unusuable (pic link below, wouldn't let me attach image bc I'm new).  Also, looks like it is formatted as MBR.  Should I wipe and format it as a GPT, or is this okay?  I don't need any of the extra partitions or to launch two different OS or anything crazy like that.  I just play games at that's it.

Thank you all.

Comment: "looks like it is formatted as MBR." - This would explain the reason it appears to be 500 GB when it's actually 2 TB?  MBR as a size limitation.  I would convert to GPT if this is a system drive.  You cannot clone MBR to a GPT disk, I would use MBR2GPT, then extend the partition after the fact.

Comment: @Ramhound MBR is surely a problem but probably not the only one. Please check my answer and suggest edits if needed. Thank you.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - A grayed out, unallocated partition, screams an MBR issue.

Comment: @Ramhound For sure (and it shouldn't happen if Macrium had been used correctly ;)) but don't you think the Gen 3 / Gen 4 compatibility is also an issue? I think that's the reason for "Disk Manager, Windows Recovery and File Explorer would not recognize it at first". My suggestion in the answer is to reinstall and GPT but also switch positions due to their different support level.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - NVMe 4 is backwards compatible with NVMe 3.  I would of course explicitly set that port to GEN 3 for obvious reasons (if applicable due to the processor)

Comment: @Ramhound edited to include the discussion about partitioning that indeed is more relevant.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried using mbr2gpt (thanks for the suggestion!!) but when I tried to /validate, it said:  Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 0.  It also said I have MS Windows Verison 10.0.19041.1 - do I have the right version to be able to use mbr2gpt?  I read somewhere about needing APK 1703 (no idea what that is or if I have it)

Comment: Do you have the right version to run MBR2GPT, absolutely, is your partition layout correct in order to use it.  Provide the partition layout for your disk as a screenshot

Comment: @Ramhound I just edited the post with the image at the top.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Your system is disk 2 not disk 0. So the validation step of MBR2GPT is correct, you don't have a OS partition on disk 0, hence the reason it failed.

Comment: @Ramhound ha makes sense!  how do i make it focus on disk 2 for all of the commands?  i didn't see it on the microsoft.com page for it and don't want to type the wrong thing in and mess more stuff up

Comment: You should follow the provided instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) to verify the disk number but it would simply be `mbr2gpt /validate /disk:2`.  Your running this against your new disk, you still have the original disk, if anything bad happens.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine. Yes, it's MBR, but that's not the issue. It mirrors disk 1 perfectly. *There is no need to convert to GPT.*

You have a lot of space that is currently not part of a partition. You cannot easily add it to the C: partition because the recovery partition is in the way.

You now have two options:

- Use a third-party partition manager to move the recovery partition to the end of the disk, then use Windows to grow the C: partition
- Create a new partition by right-clicking the unallocated space

There's some risk involved with moving partitions but the recovery partition isn't all that important anyway.

---

Next time when cloning a disk, adjust the partition layout as desired in the clone tool. All of them should support that.

Answer (score 0):

The [WD_BLACK™ SN850 NVMe™ SSD](https://www.westerndigital.com/en-us/products/internal-drives/wd-black-sn850-nvme-ssd#WDS200T1X0E) is a Gen 4 device:

> Interface **PCIe Gen4 x4**

According to the MSI's specifications for your [motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-X570-GAMING-PLUS/Specification) its secondary M.2 slot **supports only Gen 3** (with the required minimum CPU):

> M2_2 slot (from AMD® X570 Chipset)

- **Supports PCIe 3.0 x4** (2nd Gen AMD Ryzen™/ Ryzen™ 4000 G-Series,Ryzen™ with Radeon™ Vega Graphics and 2nd Gen AMD Ryzen™ with Radeon™ Graphics) and SATA 6Gb/s supports 2242/ 2260/ 2280 storage devices

The primary M.2 slot, supposedly the one already occupied by your original SSD supports PCIe 4.0 x4 if along with at least a 3rd Gen AMD Ryzen™

So, the situation as you described it is probably related with this support level details. **If you have the minimum CPU required** according to the specifications you may **try switching the positions of your new and old SSD**. That said, the situation identified by @Ramhound in comments is the key to understand the problem: **MBR partitioning** likely due to an incorrect method of cloning using Macrium is incompatible with (Windows in) UEFI mode and has a limit to the number of partitions.

In any case, **always use GPT** and avoid as much as possible or doable to clone drives. **Always prefer a fresh installation where you have full control over the target drive(s)**. Also when installing you can easily confirm whether or not the hardware details match what what they should be; when cloning you can't.

Also recommended to update UEFI and the SSDs' firmware if applicable.